# How to accept only https url's when creating the remote repository in JFrog Artifactory

Tags: maven, https, artifactory

I have just set up JFrog artifactory and I was able to point my maven project to download artifacts using this artifactory.

In JFrog 'Create Repositories' I created a 'maven' based New Remote Repository. While creating it, in the Basic section, I am able to use the following http and https type of urls in the URL field. And when I click the test button it says 'Successfully connected to  server'.

1) https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/

2) http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/

How to enforce the URL to accept only https and not http?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Since only admin users can set that field, it's assumed that such a user knows what they're doing and will use `http` or `https` appropriately. After all, if there was an option to enforce `https` in that URL, and someone wanted to set it to `http`, there would be nothing to stop them from just turning that enforcement option off, no?

Comment: I agree Darth. Thats the direction I am thinking too now. But thanks for confirming :-)